# iOS: Size of stretched View

Tags: ios, layout, view, storyboard, stretch

If the view is stretched (e.g. you stretch a view only on iPhone 5, because you have more space), self.view.size.width returns the size, which is defined in storyboard, and not the size in iPhone 5 device.

What's the reason and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be you are requesting the size to early?
I had the same expirience in viewDidLoad, but in viewWillAppear and afterwards, 
everything was layed out already correctly though the width would be returned correctly.

Comment: that could it be, but the problem is, that my component is a subclass of uiview. so there no viewWillAppear method for me. Is there a way, to check inside of a uiview, if the view was stretched / resized?

Comment: okay, i tested it... thats the problem, the view will resize, when it will appear... and i set the layout before

Comment: You can access the changed coordinates/dimensions in layoutSubviews of the derived view, as far as I can remember. Do not forget to set the view's flags correctly and call super's implementation as well.

Comment: that didn't work. i used - (void)willMoveToWindow:(UIWindow *)newWindow. in this method the new size was already set